# I want to update my table according to previous month

Tags: sql-server

```
ID      TagValue            DATESTR
1           23         2017-01-25 12:01:48.007
2           34         2017-01-25 12:01:48.007
3           44         2017-01-25 12:01:48.007
1           25         2017-02-25 12:01:48.007
2           36         2017-02-25 12:01:48.007
3           46         2017-02-25 12:01:48.007
1           27         2017-03-25 12:01:48.007
2           36         2017-03-25 12:01:48.007
3           48         2017-03-25 12:01:48.007
1           29         2017-04-25 12:01:48.007
2           38         2017-04-25 12:01:48.007
3           50         2017-04-25 12:01:48.007
1           31         2017-05-25 12:01:48.007
2           40         2017-05-25 12:01:48.007
3           52         2017-05-25 12:01:48.007
1           33         2017-06-25 12:01:48.007
2           42         2017-06-25 12:01:48.007
3           54         2017-06-25 12:01:48.007
1           44         2017-07-25 12:01:48.007
2           46         2017-07-25 12:01:48.007
3           56         2017-07-25 12:01:48.007
1           48         2017-08-25 12:01:48.007
2           58         2017-08-25 12:01:48.007
```

This is my Master table where Values are coming along with datetime

```
ID  LastMonthvalue  CurrentMonthValue   DATESTR
 1          23             25          2017-03-28 12:01:48.007
 2          34             36          2017-03-28 12:01:48.007
 3          44             46          2017-03-28 12:01:48.007
```

This is my Second Table where i want to update LastMonth Value and CurrentMonth Value  according to my master table as you can see new values are added in my  master table (ID=1) In my second table i have already 3 ID's with values suppose i want to update my second table today that is 2017-08-30 than it should update lastMonthValue value from  2017-07-25 and Update CurrentMonth Value from 2017-08-25 from Master table

Comment: This is very basic SQL.  What did you try, and what error did you get?

Comment: @R-T how you do the differentiation from start month value and end month value?

Comment: @MaurícioPontaltiNeri this is i want to know how can differentiate and update my second table according to it

Comment: Sorry I didn't pay attention that but the both Id's 1 are in different months.  I create two answers one for SQL Server 2008 and other to 2012 above

Answer (score 0):

Does it possible there multiple lines in one month?

```
;with tb(ID,TagValue,TagValue1,DATE) AS (
     select 1,234,345,'2017-07-21 13:15:09.387' union all
     select 2,444,555,'2017-07-21 13:15:09.387' union all
     select 1,356,545,'2017-08-21 13:15:09.387'
)
select ID
       ,sum(case when datediff(month,[DATE],getdate())=1 then  TagValue else 0 end) as LastMonth
       ,sum(case when datediff(month,[DATE],getdate())=0 then  TagValue else 0 end) as CurrentMonth
from tb 
where datediff(month,[DATE],getdate())<=1
group by ID
```

```
    ID  LastMonth   CurrentMonth
1   1   234 356
2   2   444 0
```

Comment: there are multiple lines in one month for every id but i have to take only 2 values from   second last month  and last month

Answer (score 0):

I create two answers one for SQL Server 2008 and other to 2012 above.

How this logic works

- cte_PreviousMonth - Discover the first day of the current month and
  previous month
- cte_Dates - get the work dates cte_Main - Filter the
  dates to retrieve the last two months
- cte_MainCurrent - calculate the last and Current values
- Update the second table

Maybe, you need do some adjusts to get your goal

```
 DECLARE @Master AS TABLE 
  ( 
     id        INT, 
     TagValue  INT,  
     DATESTR    DATETIME 
  ) 
DECLARE @Second  as table (
ID  int , LastMonthValue  int, CurrentMonthValue   int, DATESTR date)
 INSERT @Second
 VALUES 
  (1          ,23             ,25          ,'2017-03-28 12:01:48.007')
 ,(2          ,34             ,36          ,'2017-03-28 12:01:48.007')
 ,(3          ,44             ,46          ,'2017-03-28 12:01:48.007')

INSERT @Master  
VALUES 
 (1           ,23         ,'2017-01-25 12:01:48.007')
,(2           ,34         ,'2017-01-25 12:01:48.007')
,(3           ,44         ,'2017-01-25 12:01:48.007')
,(1           ,25         ,'2017-02-25 12:01:48.007')
,(2           ,36         ,'2017-02-25 12:01:48.007')
,(3           ,46         ,'2017-02-25 12:01:48.007')
,(1           ,27         ,'2017-03-25 12:01:48.007')
,(2           ,36         ,'2017-03-25 12:01:48.007')
,(3           ,48         ,'2017-03-25 12:01:48.007')
,(1           ,29         ,'2017-04-25 12:01:48.007')
,(2           ,38         ,'2017-04-25 12:01:48.007')
,(3           ,50         ,'2017-04-25 12:01:48.007')
,(1           ,31         ,'2017-05-25 12:01:48.007')
,(2           ,40         ,'2017-05-25 12:01:48.007')
,(3           ,52         ,'2017-05-25 12:01:48.007')
,(1           ,33         ,'2017-06-25 12:01:48.007')
,(2           ,42         ,'2017-06-25 12:01:48.007')
,(3           ,54         ,'2017-06-25 12:01:48.007')
,(1           ,44         ,'2017-07-25 12:01:48.007')
,(2           ,46         ,'2017-07-25 12:01:48.007')
,(3           ,56         ,'2017-07-25 12:01:48.007')
,(1           ,48         ,'2017-08-25 12:01:48.007')
,(2           ,58         ,'2017-08-25 12:01:48.007')
```

Before the update

```
SELECT * FROM @Second

ID          LastMonthValue CurrentMonthValue DATESTR
----------- -------------- ----------------- ----------
1           23             25                2017-03-28
2           34             36                2017-03-28
3           44             46                2017-03-28
```

Code ror SQL Server 2008

```
;WITH  
cte_PreviousMonth
as
(
    Select Distinct 
     Id 
    ,DateAdd(M,-1,Cast(CAST(Datepart(YYYY, Max(DATESTR) Over (Partition by Id)) * 100 +  Datepart(MM, Max(DATESTR) Over (Partition by Id)) as char(6)) +'01' as date)) DATESTR_Previous
    ,Cast(CAST(Datepart(YYYY, Max(DATESTR) Over (Partition by Id)) * 100 +  Datepart(MM, Max(DATESTR) Over (Partition by Id)) as char(6)) +'01' as date) DATESTR_CurrentStartMonth
    ,DATESTR
    from @Master 
)
,cte_Dates as
(
    Select Distinct A.Id , 
     Max(A.DATESTR) Over (Partition by A.Id) DATESTR_Previous
    ,Max(B.DATESTR) Over (Partition by B.Id) DATESTR_Current
    from @Master A 
    INNER JOIN cte_previousMonth b
    On 
     a.id = b.id and a.DATESTR >= b.DATESTR_Previous and a.DATESTR < b.DATESTR_CurrentStartMonth
)
,cte_Main AS 
(
SELECT Row_number() 
                  OVER ( 
                    partition BY id 
                    ORDER BY DATESTR) rn
                ,* 
         FROM   @Master A
         where exists (Select 1 from cte_Dates b where a.id =b.id and (a.DATESTR = b.DATESTR_Previous or a.DATESTR = b.DATESTR_Current))
)
,cte_MainCurrent as ( 
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by a.id order by a.DATESTR desc) rn
       ,a.id
       ,a.DATESTR
       ,b.tagvalue LastMonthvalue
       ,a.tagvalue CurrentMonthValue 
FROM   cte_Main a 
       LEFT JOIN cte_Main b 
              ON a.id = b.id 
                 AND a.rn = b.rn + 1 
) 
UPDATE 
    S
SET
    LastMonthValue = M.LastMonthvalue
    ,CurrentMonthValue = M.CurrentMonthValue
    ,DATESTR = M.DATESTR
FROM @Second S
INNER JOIN cte_MainCurrent M
On
    S.ID = M.id
WHERE
    M.rn = 1
```

Code For SQL Server 2012 above

```
;WITH  
cte_PreviousMonth
as
(
    Select Distinct 
     Id 
    ,DateAdd(M,-1,Cast(CAST(Datepart(YYYY, Max(DATESTR) Over (Partition by Id)) * 100 +  Datepart(MM, Max(DATESTR) Over (Partition by Id)) as char(6)) +'01' as date)) DATESTR_Previous
    ,Cast(CAST(Datepart(YYYY, Max(DATESTR) Over (Partition by Id)) * 100 +  Datepart(MM, Max(DATESTR) Over (Partition by Id)) as char(6)) +'01' as date) DATESTR_CurrentStartMonth
    ,DATESTR
    from @Master 
)
,cte_Dates as
(
    Select Distinct A.Id , 
    Max(A.DATESTR) Over (Partition by A.Id) DATESTR_Previous
    ,Max(B.DATESTR) Over (Partition by B.Id) DATESTR_Current
    from @Master A 
    INNER JOIN cte_previousMonth b
    On 
     a.id = b.id and a.DATESTR >= b.DATESTR_Previous and a.DATESTR < b.DATESTR_CurrentStartMonth
)
,cte_MainCurrent as ( 
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by a.id order by a.DATESTR desc) rn
        ,id
       ,DATESTR
       ,Lag(tagvalue, 1, NULL) 
         OVER ( 
           partition BY id 
           ORDER BY DATESTR) LastMonthvalue, 
       tagvalue             CurrentMonthValue 
FROM   @Master a
    where exists (Select 1 from cte_Dates b where a.id =b.id and (a.DATESTR = b.DATESTR_Previous or a.DATESTR = b.DATESTR_Current))
) 
UPDATE 
    S
SET
    LastMonthValue = M.LastMonthvalue
    ,CurrentMonthValue = M.CurrentMonthValue
    ,DATESTR = M.DATESTR
FROM @Second S
INNER JOIN cte_MainCurrent M
On
    S.ID = M.id
WHERE
    M.rn = 1
```

After the update

```
SELECT * FROM @Second
ID          LastMonthValue CurrentMonthValue DATESTR
----------- -------------- ----------------- ----------
1           44             48                2017-08-25
2           46             58                2017-08-25
3           54             56                2017-07-25
```

Comment: this is not i want this query make multiple entries of ID 1

Comment: Can you enhance your example to expose the situation that is not covered?

Comment: I have Enhanced my query so you can easily understand the stiuation

Comment: @R-T, I create a new version, I hope it works for you.